# Can I add pattern attribute with input type as number?

Tags: html, validation, input, attr

Here I have a `HTML5` input.....

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d{10}" data-pattern-msg="enter a value according to the pattern" />
```

But this is not validating this pattern  ......
What is the reason for this ??

Comment: this is working when type is as "text". but I need type as "number". Can someone explain what is the reason to not working when the type as "number"??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML Checker (validator) here. The reason the checker is emitting an error for your example is that the HTML spec doesn’t allow the `pattern` attribute to be specified for `<input type=number>` elements; see the *The following content attributes must not be specified and do not apply to the element* list in the **Bookkeeping details** section of [the section on the HTML spec on `<input type=number>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29).

And I’m not sure that most browsers support using `placeholder` with `<input type=number>`.

Comment: Hello, however, I just tested it with Edge 115.0.1901.203, Firefox 116.0.3 and Chrome 116.0.5845.97, and they seem to take this into account.
<input type="number" id="every" min=1 max=10  pattern="^[0-9]+$" inputmode="numeric" step="1">
May be they should not but it seems to run.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong  `type = "number"` change to `type="text"` and try

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{10}" data-pattern-msg="enter a value according to the pattern" title="only number" />
```

Definition and Usage
The pattern attribute specifies a regular expression that the  element's value is checked against.

**Note:** The pattern attribute works with the following **input types: text, search, url, tel, email, and password.**

**Tip:** Use the global title attribute to describe the pattern to help the user.

Comment: It's true, it is the wrong use of pattern but I am sure OP has a reason to use type="number"